# Is it possible to have shared python library in GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, shared-libraries

I want to share some modules between a python GAE project, and another python project but want to use the same source files so that I can change them without having to worry about keeping the source files in each project up to date.

Is there a way to let two python projects share the same source files outside of their root? Also let GAE know which source files exist outside of the source tree so it deploys them to the server. I'm using PyDev on Eclipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IF your dev environment is linux, you can use symlinks in your project folder to the shared source.  The deployment will treat the symlinks as actual files/folders.

Comment: Works fine on OS X, as well, not just linux. I'm not sure about Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The deploy tools for Google App Engine (in the Python world at least) don't know anything about shared projects in Eclipse. You point the deploy script to a folder and that's about it.
You can create a script that will copy the projects into a deploy folder and deploy that folder.

Comment: That's what I expected. But thought maybe there is a better way.

Comment: @aligf leave it open, I also hope there is a better way.